# Strange behaviour of an array returned by a function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Why does this code work:

```
$row = $stmt->fetch();
$result = array("status"=>"0", "uid"=>($row["id"]));
```

And this one does not:

```
$result = array("status"=>"0", "uid"=>(($stmt->fetch())["id"]));
```

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate and thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since PHP 5.4 it's possible to do what you did.

```
getSomeArray()[$someKey]
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-88

Prior to PHP 5.3, you'll need to use a temporary variable.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know they had added that in PHP 5.4.

Comment: @MattBrowne I know, its quite useful

Comment: Why do people keep downvoting this? In PHP 5.3 or below a temporary variable is indeed the only way to accomplish this.

Comment: @MattBrowne I am close to exploding. I was so happy when I saw that big 3...

Comment: @MattBrowne it's especially weird since all the downvoters lost 1 rep...

Comment: +1 +55/-8  Four upvotes + accept / 4 downvotes :P

Comment: @Vivek i can live with that ;)

Comment: Though i didn't really understand it but after reading the comments i thought that its a good answer and deserves an Upvote ;)

Comment: @Vivek you didn't understand it? Join the club :)

Comment: @imulsion After visiting that link i understood it :)